# Writing a MYSQL Following Users Query

Tags: mysql

I'm building an app where a user can follow other users and be followed.

A user can also look at who another user is following.

Now lets say **user1** is looking at who **user2** is following, I need to find all the people IDs that user2 is following and compare it against who user1 is following.

*Instead of* returning only the IDs of all the users that match both user1 and user2 (which I've seen in other forums), I need to retrieve all user2's following IDs and User Names as well as a flag that indicates if the followed person is also followed by user1.

I've got it to work in PHP with a double for loop of each Query, but I worry that this code will be expensive and would be far better optimized with a single MYSQL query.

Relevant tables and columns:

```
following_table
  follower_id
  followed_id
  following: varchar -- 'true' or 'false'

user_table
  user_id
  user_name
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
$user_id1 = '1991';
$myFollowingQuery = "SELECT following_table.followed_id, user_table.user_name
                     FROM following_table 
                     INNER JOIN user_table ON
                     following_table.followed_id = user_table.user_id
                     WHERE following_table.following = 'true'
                     AND following_table.follower_id = '$user_id1'";

$user_id2 = '1985';
$userFollowingQuery = "SELECT following_table.followed_id, user_table.user_name
                       FROM following_table 
                       INNER JOIN user_table ON
                          following_table.followed_id = user_table.user_id
                       WHERE following_table.following = 'true'
                       AND following_table.follower_id = '$user_id2'";

$userFollowingResult = mysql_query($userFollowingQuery) 
                             or doResponse('error',"Couldn't connect to the database");
$myFollowingResult = mysql_query($myFollowingQuery) 
                             or doResponse('error',"Couldn't connect to the database");

            for($i = 0; $i< mysql_num_rows($userFollowingResult);$i++){

$loopArray = array(followed_id => mysql_result($userFollowingResult,$i,"followed_id"),
                   followed_name => mysql_result($userFollowingResult,$i,"user_name"));

for($j = 0; $j< mysql_num_rows($myFollowingResult);$j++){
  if(mysql_result($userFollowingResult,$i,"followed_id")
     ==mysql_result($myFollowingResult,$j,"followed_id")) {
     $loopArray['is_following'] = 'true';
     break;
  }
  if($j==mysql_num_rows($myFollowingResult)-1){
    $loopArray['is_following'] = 'false';
    break;
  }
}

$resultArray[$i] = $loopArray;
}

echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, is it like a mutual followings listing you want?

Comment: Can you please paste the table structure too (`show create table TABLE_NAME`). From what I can guess you can use MINUS, INTERSECT to resolve your problem.

Comment: Sorry to be a newbie. Never used (show create table TABLE_NAME). Tried to get it to work with Querious but got no results. Basically the following_table consist of:

follower_id | followed_id | date_created | following(true or false.)

the user_table consists of:

user_id | user_name | followers | following | etc., etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b8d6/3

```
SELECT
  user.user_id,
  user.user_name,
  he.follower_id AS follower_id,
  IF(me.followed_id,1,0) AS metoo

FROM       following AS he

INNER JOIN user
   ON user.user_id = he.followed_id

LEFT  JOIN following AS me
   ON me.follower_id = 1
  AND me.followed_id = he.followed_id

WHERE he.follower_id = 2
```

Comment: Very cool. Is there anyway to get he.followed_name from the user_table?

This is the Final JSON I'm trying to get:
{"followed_id":"27","followed_name":"userNameHere","is_following":"true"}

Comment: You rock so much! That worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Of course it works only, when (follower,followed) is a unique pair in the followers table, otherwise the above query would make some duplicate rows.

Comment: @biziclop is there any chance in posting a SQLFiddle showing a situation where in the same way user1 is looking at users that follow user2 and show the users that user 1 is following in a boolean? I have been struggling with this for a while and your code here gets me 80% of the way. Thanks!